# Devices cannot connect to my shared Wi-Fi

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, internet-sharing

I have a Late-2016 MacBook Pro without Touch Bar.

When I create a shared Wi-Fi network through System Preferences -> Sharing (while I have my machine connected to ethernet via a USB-C adaptor), no device can connect.

The network is configured with WPA-2 personal security (just a password, though I have also tried with no security and end up with the same result).

When I try to connect with security enabled, my iPhone always says incorrect password (though I've confirmed the password is correct). When I try to connect without any security, my iPhone just says unable to connect. I have had colleagues try with their phones and computers with the same results.

Any recommendations?

Comment: I've seen a few similar issues on various boards and nobody has a solid resolution yet.  [This person](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7867393) states they spent several hours with Apple support and was told it needs to go back to Engineering for a fix so it might just be a bug.

Comment: Do you still have this problem or is it fixed?

Comment: Could you include in your original question a screen capture of your: `System Preferences > Sharing > Wi-Fi Options...`?

Answer (score 1):

Head to the Genius Bar and show them. If they deem it to be a hardware issue they may replace the defective board.